# Non native writers who learned English late

Tags: language

Does there exist example of non native English writer who learned the language late in life?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not seem to be about writing.

Answer (score 2):

Joseph Conrad learned English in his twenties.

Sources:

- [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Conrad)
- [e-notes](http://www.enotes.com/topics/joseph-conrad)